# UserMailer erroring on <% end %> within an <% end %> why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a UserMailer template that is text. Inside the text view I have the following:

```
<% if !@thing.empty? %>
  <% @thing.each do |id, count| %>
    <%= #{count}%> <%= #{id} %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This seems fine but it errors with?

```
ActionView::Template::Error: /app/views/user_mailer/user_daily_activity.text.erb:12: unterminated string meets end of file
/app/views/user_mailer/myfile.text.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
```

Any idea why rails is erroring on this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{count}` format is only for use within strings, not as a standalone reference. Since you're not using it in a string, the `#` is interpreted as a comment.

Try this instead:

```
<%= count %> <%= id %>
```

This would also be equivalent:

```
<%= "#{count} #{id}" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to comment in your `.html.erb` view. Your 3rd line is acting as comment.

```
<% if !@thing.empty? %>
  <% @thing.each do |id, count| %>
    <%= "#{count}" %> <%= "#{id}" %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```